# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable when getting a Class property in Python

Tags: python, class

I have these two simple classes, residing in two different files:

**dialogs.py**

```
import wx
import wx.adv

class Dialogs():

    def __init__(self):
        self._InputValue = ""

        def DialogInput(self, message, title, defaultvalue=""):
        dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, message, title)

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            print("User enetered: {}".format(dlg.GetValue()))
            self._InputValue = dlg.GetValue()
        dlg.Destroy()
        return self

    @property
    def InputValue(self):
        return self._InputValue
```

**dbinit.py:**

```
from dialogs import Dialogs

class DBInit:

    def __init__(self):
        dlg = Dialogs()
        dlg.DialogInput("Please enter your name", "Input Required")
        print(dlg.InputValue())
```

The last statement (print) throws this error:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: Look, is `dlg.InputValue` a function or a string?

Comment: `InputValue` is a property. It's not a function you can call, so you need to remove the parentheses. `print(dlg.InputValue)`

Comment: Your indentation is wrong in `DialogInput`. Probably sloppy copy and paste, and not related to your immediate issue. Still fix it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python will try to call the `dlg.InputValue()` functione because you put a pair of parentheses after `dlg.InputValue`

But a string property is not callable... (because it's not a function!)

Loose the parentheses:`()` and your code should work:

**dbinit.py:**

```
from dialogs import Dialogs

class DBInit:

    def __init__(self):
        dlg = Dialogs()
        dlg.DialogInput("Please enter your name", "Input Required")
        print(dlg.InputValue)
```

Answer (score 3):

A property doesn't need calling:

```
print(dlg.InputValue)
```